# please help me out for this query

Tags: sql-server

i given the countryId and countrname as 33 and india if i give the same countryid and countryname it has to give the message as updated.  please tell me the code for that.. I wrote like this

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  Table1 WHERE CountryName=@CountryName )
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'already exists'
    END 
ELSE BEGIN
    UPDATE Table1
    SET
        CountryName = @CountryName 
    WHERE CountryId   = @CountryId                               
    SELECT @QStatus = 'values updated';
END
```

Comment: Please edit the title to be more related to the matter of query and please format the question to be readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `IF` statement logic is not correct. `UPDATE` is used to *change* existing rows, so if the row does not exist there is nothing to `UPDATE`.

You need to use `INSERT`

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  Table1 WHERE CountryName=@CountryName )
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'already exists'
    END 
ELSE BEGIN
    INSERT Table1 (CountryName, CountryId)
    VALUES (@CountryName, CountryId)                               
    SELECT @QStatus = 'values inserted';
END
```

However, if what you need to do is replace the country name of the `ID` passed in you can use

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  Table1 WHERE CountryId=@CountryId )
BEGIN
    UPDATE Table1
    SET
        CountryName = @CountryName 
    WHERE CountryId   = @CountryId                               
    SELECT @QStatus = 'values updated';
END
```

From the SQL you have provided it's hard to tell what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: thanks for giving me the answer.. i have one more doubt can you clarify it?

Comment: Suppose we given same country id with different CountryName. It has to display Updated successfully. so can you tell me code for that

Comment: The second SQL statement in my answer does this. If a row exists matching the `ID` passed in it updates the name to the parameter `@CountryName`.